# C# Return type error

Tags: c#

So here is my code:

```
public class landen
{
    public static List<Land> Lijst()
    {
        List<Land> lijst = new List<Land>
        {
            new Land("AF,AFG,Afghanistan,Islamitische Republiek AFghanistan,Kaboel,0093"),
            new Land("AL,ALB,Albanië,Republiek Albanië, Tirana,00355"),
            new Land("DZ,DZA,Algerije,Democratische Volksrepubliek Algerije,Algiers,00213")
        };
        return lijst;
    }
}
```

my error is:

> Error    CS0050    Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'List' is less accessible than method 'landen.Lijst()'

Comment: Are you using List from System.Collection namespace or is it a custom class defined by you?

Comment: this is a new class, not in the form1.cs

Comment: Can you show your List class declaration?

Comment: Your **List** class must be public.

Comment: If you are using a custom defined List class, could you post the code where this class is declared. E.g.: public List{ ... }

Comment: The class `Land` is declared as internal. Remember, if you declared the class without an explicit modifier, the class will be internal, i.e., `class Land { }` will be internal. Add the public modifier: `public class Land { }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is indicating, you are trying to return an instance of a class that has a visibility modifier - e.g. private, internal, protected, public - that is less accessible than your method.

As your method `public static List<Land> Lijst()` is public you should check for the visibility of List class.

You can only return instances of List in this case from methods that has the same or higher accessibility. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx) to know more about the restrictions when using accessibility levels:

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) in order to know the levels of accessibility in C#.

> From greater access privilege to lower:

**public:** Access is not restricted.

**protected:** Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.

**internal:** Access is limited to the current assembly.

**protected internal:** Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class.

**private:** Access is limited to the containing type.

You should have your List class defined somewhere as:

```
**public** class List
{
...
}
```

Maybe it's defined as internal or protected internal, or even doesn't have any modifier and then it's private and hence your are receiving this error.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of error occurs if you have a custom List class, and it is less accessible than the method itself.

Consider making your custom list public. That should solve the problem.